# failed to open stream: Permission denied in Laravel

Tags: linux, laravel, permissions, laravel-5.6

I use a Laravel Project in Windows Its work Fine But When I try to use in my Linux Xampp. Its show error

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

I giver permission 755 but still not work .

But when I give permission to 777 its work fine.

I think 777 has bad implementation

Comment: You should try to change the owner of the folder instead. Maybe apache.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others?answertab=active#tab-top), it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You Try `sudo chmod -R 755 ./your _project_folder` Open terminal project directory

Comment: yes 777 Permission i work fine but i think it has some security issue

Answer (score 0):

Never set 777 directory permission. Make directory owner to be the current user, set webserver user as the group.

Run

```
 sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage 

 sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

set permissions.

```
 chmod -R 775 storage 
 chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```